# Remove numbers from string in R

Tags: r, gsub

I'm trying to remove all the number except 67 from string by using the function `gsub`.

**For example:**

```
txt <- "A function 147832 for 67cleaning 67 data 6 7"
```

**Desire output:**

```
txt <- "A function for 67cleaning 67 data"
```

I've tried `txt = gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", txt)`, but it will remove all the numbers.

Comment: All the numbers except 6 and 7 or all the numbers except "67"? What does the string look like? What should the output be for "9876543210"? What about "1 2 67 3" vs "12673"?

Comment: @nico It's 67. For example, `x="I like apple 67 12 123"`, I want it to become `x="I like apple 67"`. About `1 2 3  67 3`, expected result is `67`; About `123673`, expected result is "nothing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this

```
x = unlist(strsplit(txt, split = '\\s+')) # split your string
paste0(x[Reduce(`|`, lapply(c('[A-Za-z]', '67'), grepl, x))], collapse = ' ') # use the list of regular expression to match the required pattern and put them all together

#[1] "A function for 67cleaning 67 data"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I tried in R, the result is `[1] "c(\"A\", \"function\", \"147832\", \"for\", \"67cleaning\", \"67\", \"data\", \"6\", \"7\")"`, I don't know why.

Comment: @velvetrock I have edited the answer now it should work

Answer (score 4):

it's not super elegant but you can do it in three steps:

```
 tmp <- gsub("67", "XX", "A function 147832 for 67cleaning 67 data 6 7")
 tmp <- gsub("\\d+", "", tmp)
 tmp <- gsub("XX", "67", tmp)
 tmp
 #"A function  for 67cleaning 67 data  "
```

first substitute all instances of `67` with a marker (say, `XX`), then delete all other remaining numbers, finally sub `67` back in.